# How to type hint that a function returns another function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following two functions:

```
def payment_failed(user: User, charge: Charge, type: str) -> HttpResponse:
    # ... do something here
    return HttpResponse(status=200)


def payment_canceled(*args):
    return payment_failed(*args)
```

I also want to use type hinting for the `payment_canceled` function but I'm not sure which version is correct.

Version 1:

```
def payment_canceled(*args) -> payment_failed:
    return payment_failed(*args)
```

Version 2:

```
def payment_canceled(*args) -> HttpResponse:
    return payment_failed(*args)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the function at all if it just returns the other?

Comment: You can type hint functions as [Callables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable).

Comment: The second; `payment_canceled` just returns whatever `payment_failed` returns, not `payment_failed` itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`payment_canceled` *doesn't* return another function; it calls `payment_failed` and returns whatever it returns. The second is correct:

```
def payment_canceled(*args) -> HttpResponse:
    return payment_failed(*args)
```

If you really *were* returning a function, `Callable` from the `typing` module would be appropriate.

```
from typing import Callable

def payment_canceled(*args) -> Callable[Tuple[Any],HttpResponse]:
    return payment_failed
```